# PHPUnit Selenium Server - Better/Custom Error Handling?

Tags: php, testing, selenium, phpunit

Is there a way I can have PHPUnit just continue after an error?  For example, I have a large test suite (400+ steps) and I would prefer that if say, an element is not found, it doesn't stop the rest of my script from continuing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better way to do this. Instead of overloading every assert*() method you can overload just one method: runTest(). It is for each assertion, and exceptions can be caught:

```
abstract class AMyTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function runTest()
    {
        try {
            parent::runTest();
        }
        catch ( MyCustomException $Exc ) {
            // will continue tests
        }
        catch ( Exception $Exc ) {
            if ( false === strpos($Exc->getMessage(), 'element not found') ) {
                // rethrow:
                throw $Exc;
            }
            // will also continue
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We do the same thing in our Selenium tests. You need to catch the exceptions thrown for assertion failures, and the only way to do that is to create a custom test case base class that overrides the assertion methods. You can store the failure messages and fail the test at the end using a test listener.

I don't have the code in front of me, but it was pretty straight-forward. For example,

```
abstract class DelayedFailureSeleniumTestCase extends PHPUnit_Extension_SeleniumTestCase
{
    public function assertElementText($element, $text) {
        try {
            parent::assertElementText($element, $text);
        }
        catch (PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedException $e) {
            FailureTrackerListener::addAssertionFailure($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    ... other assertion functions ...
}

class FailureTrackerListener implements PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener
{
    private static $messages;

    public function startTest() {
        self::$messages = array();
    }

    public static function addAssertionFailure($message) {
        self::$messages[] = $message;
    }

    public function endTest() {
        if (self::$messages) {
            throw new PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedException(
                    implode("\n", self::$messages));
        }
    }
}
```